# How can I access a MySQL database on AWS RDS from my desktop?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am a Java developer, and I have coded a plain Java application that creates a MySQL database from a text file.  I'm using MySQL version 8.0.19 and the Java MySQL connector 5.1.48.

The code is rather straightforward.  I create three tables and insert rows into the tables.  On my local MySQL, I can see the three tables and their contents using the MySQL Workbench.

I access my local MySQL database with the following host:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bible?useSSL=false
```

My user id is "root".

When I try to connect to the MySQL database on AWS RDS, with the following host, I get connection denied errors.

```
jdbc:mysql://bible-database.caaitaoyrsgq.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

I've changed the URL slightly to protect myself.

When I try to access my AWS RDS MySQL database, I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:335)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.ggl.bible.database.sql.SQL.connect(SQL.java:31)
    at com.ggl.bible.database.BuildDatabase.processBible(BuildDatabase.java:30)
    at com.ggl.bible.database.BuildDatabase.main(BuildDatabase.java:19)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:299)
    ... 18 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ggl.bible.database.sql.SQL.createBibleTables(SQL.java:99)
    at com.ggl.bible.database.BuildDatabase.processBible(BuildDatabase.java:31)
    at com.ggl.bible.database.BuildDatabase.main(BuildDatabase.java:19)
```

I know I have a connection problem.

I've looked at some guides online, like [Connecting to a DB Instance Running the MySQL Database Engine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html), but I don't understand what the author is telling me.

Is there a guide for simple minds like mine that will give me step by step instructions on how to connect?  When I say simple, I mean:

1. Go to web page ...
2. Left click on the link that says ...
3. Type this in the box next to ...

Thanks for any assistance I might get.

Comment: you  have to use a ssl encrypted connection. The port isn't reachable directly from the internet, because of security reasons, so you first establish a ss cpnnection and communinacate with mysql serv over that connection.see response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536391/5193536

Comment: @nbk that is not a requirement to establish a connection, it is only a best practice. The link you shared is only for adding SSL support in a Java app, it is not directly related to solving the network connectivity issue in this question. The RDS instance (or a bastion host or VPN server in the same VPC) would have to be exposed to the Internet in some way for a connection to work from a user's desktop computer.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079211/connecting-to-amazon-rds-mysql-remotely
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412850/connecting-to-aws-rds-remotely-without-key-using-workbench-or-other-mysql-utilit
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778263/can-not-remote-connect-to-rds-db-instance-of-aws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to expose your database to the internet:

> 1 step: [enable internet on your vpc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)
>
> 2 step: route your database subnets to the internetgateway
>
> 3 step: On your rds instance options, check "Public accessibility", save and restart the instance

And dont forget to create the rule to allow traffic from your ip in the security group.

Comment: No, you should expose your database to the world, that is why a ssl connction should be established

Comment: The AWS article you linked to is filled with the same unintelligible jargon  I've been reading and not understanding.  The Amazon people are supposed to be the network wizards, not me.

Comment: We are obviously not talking about a production environment. There is no harm using like this for developent purposes.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc well, that is simpler as it gets, VPC 101. If you are having a hard time understanding this, maybe you should go back to the basics. No offense.

Answer (score 1):

I finally successfully connected to a MySQL database on AWS RDS.

I now understand Stargazer's answer better, because I came across a YouTube video, [AWS RDS MySQL Database Setup | Step by Step Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ng_zi11N4_c&feature=youtu.be).

I had two main problems with my MySQL database, which I was able to correct by deleting the database instance I created three days ago and creating a new database instance today.

1. My database wasn't open to public access.  When you set up a database on RDS, one of the standard options is public or private access.  I did not notice this option when I set up my first database instance.
2. The YouTube video showed me exactly how to add an inbound rule to the VPC security groups.
3. On the database summary page, on the right side, under Security, is a list of the VPC security groups.  Left-click on the default group, which brings you to the EC2 dashboard.
4. Under Security Group ID, left-click on the security group id.  This brings you to a web page where you can alter the inbound and outbound rules.  You need to add an inbound rule from your IP address.  My inbound rule looks like this.  I've masked my IP address.

   All traffic All All 68.xxx.121.68/32    My laptop

Anyway, I hope my question and this answer helps someone in the future.  All the guides I read from Amazon assume that you create 30 database instances a day, and know all of these network concerns inside and out.  Me, I just want to write Alexa skills using Java.  The database is just a means to that end.